# Search results is null when ViewsLifeTime field is included and Queried via Rest api

Tags: search, rest

I'm trying to do a search with the REST API sorting by ViewsLifeTime but the result search contains documents with ViewsLifeTime value is null, how can I avoid that?

Comment: what is the SharePoint version you are referring

Comment: Sharepoint online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enable *Search* and *Query* property for "**ViewsLifeTime**" managed property in search service and perform full crawl.

Use Search Query API for not returning the items for which "**ViewsLifeTime**" count is null

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='NOT(viewslifetime:0)'
```

Reference Links :- 
[Filter for Empty Values in Search][1]