# Get page views of a page in SharePoint using Javascript

Tags: search, 2016, crawl, search-api

Is there a way to get the total number of page views of a page in SharePoint using Rest API or JSOM?

I tried using Search API

```
http://SiteUrl/sites/_api/search/query?querytext='home'
```

But in all the results, the ViewsLifeTime is null
I  enabled search and crawl for the managed property (ViewsLifeTime) and ran a full crawl as suggested [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150823/), but still the values were null.

Also the `ViewsRecent` column is null as well

Is there any other way ? Am I missing something like a mapping?

Comment: `ViewsLifeTime` is updated around every 2 weeks while `ViewsRecent` shows visitors of the recent time span. Have you had your page at least for the couple of weeks so that `ViewsLifeTime` could have received some value?

Comment: Yeah the page has been there for almost a month now. but I've enabled search & crawl in the managed meta data only today, does that matter?

Comment: ViewsRecent also returns null value. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: Yes it probably does matter that it's been put under crawling only recently.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using parameters:/_api/search/query?querytext='home'&selectproperties='Recent Views'

this site goes into pretty good detail of using the search api:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview